# My site looks different when activating new theme

Tags: themes

I'm working on my site [ontwik.com](http://ontwik.com/), just created a new design and uploaded it and when I activate, it works fine for the homepage and otherpages. but the problem is when i lo gout from wordpress admin or open ontwik in a different browser the homepage looks great but the other pages using the old theme.

I tried to activate my oldest themes to see if the problem from the new theme but still there.

You can visit the site now and check for difference.

Thanks

Comment: You're using WP Super Cache; reset the cache for the problem page(s) and it should display the new design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using WP Super Cache; reset the cache for the problem page(s) and it should display the new design.

The reason it looks different when you're logged in is because the static pages are served to

1. Users who are not logged in.
2. Users who have not left a comment on your blog.
3. Or users who have not viewed a password protected post.

Comment: After days of searching, Now I can keep the new design to the world, Thanks so much for your help. I reset the cache and every thing is ok.